# How can i find my data source name for my SQL Server 2008?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a data connection

```
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:\\a\\b\\bd.mdf';Integrated Security=True;
Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

With what am I supposed to replace `.\\SQLEXPRESS` and where can I find the desired information?

I used to have SQL Server Express 2008 but now I have installed SQL Server 2008 full version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be your computer name, but you have to replace more than just that.

```
Data Source=myServerAddress; Initial Catalog=myDataBase; Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Comment: could you detail? what i have to do more?

Answer (score 1):

Replace . With your server name.  You need server name and your instance name. Your instance is usually default instance name or whatever you named it. Use localhost if it's the same server.

Catalog name as well is the name of the database. You can see these names in SQL mgmt studio.